# How to using try and catch correctly to force loop go to next iteration?

Tags: matlab

So I know how the try and catch work, but it wont go to next iteration correctly. 
I already know this line will casue problem becasue the input files.

`[position, velocity] = states(sat, time, "CoordinateFrame", "ecef");`

But there are too much so I dont have time to check each one.
Therefore I use try to hold the all main part of my loop. 
However after it got error and go into catch part, actually it will go to next iteration.

[image: screenshot]

It wont do the calculation for the next TLE file and output the [position, velocity], which I need.
 
And the value will stay in the first error one.

[image: screenshot 2]

How can I let it work correctly? thanks.

full code in https://pastecode.io/s/zhf5pr01
for loop part :

```
% Loop through each TLE file    
for i = 1:7758
    tleFile = tleFiles{i};
    tleFilePath = tleFile;
    [epochYearArray, month, day] = extractTLEData(tleFilePath);
    
    try
        % Create the satellite object using the TLE file
        sat = satellite(sc, tleFile);
        
        % Calculate the year for the specified date
        year = 2000 + epochYearArray;
        
        % Specify the time for which you want to get position and velocity
        time = datetime(year, month, day, 12, 0, 0);

        % Compute position and velocity in ECEF coordinate frame
        [position, velocity] = states(sat, time, "CoordinateFrame", "ecef");

        % Display the results
        disp("TLE File: " + tleFile);
        position_realn(i) = (norm(position') / 1000) - 6371;
        velocity_realn(i) = norm(velocity') / 1000;
        disp(time);
        disp("Position (ECEF) [km]: " + position_realn(i));
        disp("Velocity (ECEF) [km/s]: " + velocity_realn(i));
        disp("-------------------------------");

    catch exception
        fprintf('Inconsistent data in iteration %d, skipped.\n', i);
        disp("Error Message: " + exception.message);
    end
end
```

Comment: It is unclear what the problem is or what your question is. The loop seems to continue fine after an exception is raised. Please create a [mre], it will help illustrate your problem, the current code is too large to understand where the problem is. Also, please use periods at the end of sentences and start sentences with an uppercase letter. These are established conventions for writing English that greatly enhance our ability to read your sentences.

Comment: Hi @Cris Luengo, thanks for let me know!! I already edited it, hope this will be help!

Comment: Are you saying that you expect some of these files to cause an error and want to skip them, but your current code then wrongly skips all of the files after that? Have you tried starting the loop from the index after the first one that throws the error and checking if the behaviour is the same? Also, have you inspected the full [contents of the exception object](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mexception.html#mw_72498c03-c4e8-48bb-8704-0a6b8e02679b) inside your `catch` block, for example by setting a breakpoint inside this block?